# how to get rgb value from sensor_msgs/image

Tags: ros, image-raw, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i need to use rgb value from /camera/color/image_raw topic. i want to know how to get rgb value from this topic.
thank you for answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315043/how-to-get-rgb-value-from-sensor_msgs/image/) by [Cinnamoroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/39912/cinnamoroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, First you might need to convert the image from ros message image to open cv image using  [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge), then use the available functions of Opencv to read color values, like

```
cv:: Mat image ;
Point3_<uchar>* p =image.ptr< Point3_<uchar> > (y,x);
p->x //B
p->y //R
p->z //G
```

and probably you can find other methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932893/accessing-certain-pixel-rgb-value-in-opencv)

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cinnamoroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/39912/cinnamoroll/) on 2019-02-22**:
thanks bro !!

**Comment by [Cinnamoroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/39912/cinnamoroll/) on 2019-02-22**:
the last question what is a y and x in p =image.ptr< Point3_ > (y,x) ? width and and height right ?

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-02-22**:
yes, x,y are the pixel coordinates (width and height )